# CellList and multiple DataProviders

Tags: gwt, dataprovider, celllist

Is it possible to switch `CellList` between several `DataProvider`s?
For example `ListDataProvider` and `AsyncDataProvider`?

```
dataProviderAsync.addDataDisplay(getView().getCellList());
dataProviderList.addDataDisplay(getView().getCellList());
```

I can add some providers, but I can't clean datadisplay

```
public Set<HasData<T>> getDataDisplays() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(displays);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not have many data providers for one data display at one time (you can have many displays for one data provider).

However you can change data provider at run-time.

If you want to switch between data providers (I guess when new data arrives on `AsyncDataDrovider`) you can override `onRangeChanged()` of your data provider and change data display.

One important thing is that `onRangeChanged()` is fired when there is a data display added to the provider. So you have to add some 'dummy' display, wait for data and then change display.